# RPM compression not working with spring-boot gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Ive made a spring boot project with gradle, and have made an rpm build for it. The jar file works fine before i run my rpm, but after its compressed i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/castor-core-1.3.3.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/castor-core-1.3.3.jar'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:104)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/castor-core-1.3.3.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:281)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:249)
    ... 6 more
```

I have tried diabling rpms compression with %global __os_install_post %{nil} at the top of my .spec file, and then it works. So ive narrowed it down to my issue being that it is compressed when i build the rpm. However im not really interested in it not being compressed, as  the file may eventually get rather large . So how do i actually fix this. Do i have to add something to gradle telling it to decompress before running or something?

rpm was build with this .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script expects the Jenkins job to have moved the securityservice-files into the rpmbuild/SOURCES dir
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
source common.sh

# Remove old RPMS, just for good measure
rm -rf rpmbuild/RPMS/*

# Move build files into SOURCES
cp ../sf_securityservice/build/libs/securityservice-0.0.1.jar rpmbuild/SOURCES
cp ../sf_securityservice/dist-resources/log4j2.xml rpmbuild/SOURCES
cp ../sf_securityservice/dist-resources/config.xml rpmbuild/SOURCES


#Define paths
BIN_DIR=$C3A_BIN_DIR/securityservice
ETC_DIR=$C3A_ETC_DIR/securityservice
LOG_DIR=$C3A_LOG_DIR/securityservice
VAR_DIR=$C3A_VAR_DIR/securityservice


JDK_VERSION_STRING=$(select_java_version "Frankfurt")
RELEASE=$(package_version)
VERSION="1.0"


#Set default args
cat <<DEFAULT_ARGS > rpmbuild/SOURCES/default_args
#
# Changes in this file WILL be replaced on update.
# Persistent changes goes in ${ETC_DIR}/custom_args.
#

JVM_ARGS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/c3a/etc/securityservice/log4j2.xml"
CMD_ARGS="${ETC_DIR}/config.xml"
DEFAULT_ARGS

#Make empty file for custom args
touch rpmbuild/SOURCES/custom_args

cat <<RUNSH > rpmbuild/SOURCES/run.sh
#!/bin/bash

source $BIN_DIR/default_args
source $ETC_DIR/custom_args
/usr/bin/java \$JVM_ARGS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -jar $BIN_DIR/securityservice-0.0.1.jar \$CMD_ARGS

RUNSH

cat <<EOF > rpmbuild/SOURCES/c3a-securityservice.service
[Unit]
Description=Cetrea SecurityService
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=$VAR_DIR
User=securityservice
Group=c3a
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=900
StartLimitBurst=3
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=$BIN_DIR/run.sh
SyslogIdentifier=cas
LimitNOFILE=25000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

cd rpmbuild
rm -rf ./BUILDROOT/*

rpmbuild --target noarch \
    -D "VERSION $VERSION" \
    -D "RELEASE $RELEASE" \
    -D "BIN_DIR $BIN_DIR" \
    -D "ETC_DIR $ETC_DIR" \
    -D "LOG_DIR $LOG_DIR" \
    -D "VAR_DIR $VAR_DIR" \
    -D "JDK_VERSION_STRING $JDK_VERSION_STRING" \
    -D "_topdir ${PWD}" \
    -bb SPECS/securityservice.spec

RPM=$DIR/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/securityservice-${VERSION}-${RELEASE}.noarch.rpm
echo $RPM
```

and this .spec

```
%description 
this package contains Cetrea SecurityService.


%prep
#Unpack the release here using %setup

%build
#nothing here

%install
#Make target folders
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{LOG_DIR}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{BIN_DIR}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{ETC_DIR}
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{VAR_DIR}

mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system/
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/c3a-securityservice.service $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system/

# Copy things into said folders
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/default_args $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{BIN_DIR}
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/run.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{BIN_DIR}
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/custom_args $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{ETC_DIR}
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/log4j2.xml $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{ETC_DIR}
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/config.xml $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{ETC_DIR}
cp $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/securityservice.log $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{VAR_DIR}

install -m 644 $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/securityservice-0.0.1.jar $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{BIN_DIR}/

%pre
groupadd c3a || true
useradd -d %{VAR_DIR} -g c3a securityservice || true

%post
# Start the SecurityService once the install has completed
systemctl daemon-reload
if [ $1 -gt 1 ] ; then
    echo "restart SecurityService"
    systemctl restart c3a-securityservice || true
else
    echo "start SecurityService"
    systemctl enable c3a-securityservice || true
    systemctl start c3a-securityservice || true
fi

%preun
# the preun section is where you can run commands before the rpm is removed

if [ $1 == 0 ] ; then
    echo "stop SecurityService"
    systemctl stop c3a-securityservice || true
    systemctl disable c3a-securityservice || true
    systemctl daemon-reload
    systemctl reset-failed c3a-securityservice || true
fi

%clean
#rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
#rm -rf %{_tmppath}/%{name}
#rm -rf %{_topdir}/BUILD/%{name}

%files
# list files owned by the package here
%attr(-, securityservice, c3a) %dir %{BIN_DIR}
%attr(-, securityservice, c3a) %dir %{LOG_DIR}
%attr(-, securityservice, c3a) %dir %{VAR_DIR}

%attr(644, securityservice, c3a) %{BIN_DIR}/securityservice-0.0.1.jar
%attr(-, securityservice, c3a) %{BIN_DIR}/default_args
%attr(750, securityservice, c3a) %{BIN_DIR}/run.sh
%attr(-,securityservice, c3a) %VAR_DIR/securityservice.log
%attr(664, securityservice, c3a) %config(noreplace) %{ETC_DIR}/*

/usr/lib/systemd/system/c3a-securityservice.service

%changelog
```

The gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RC2'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group = 'com.cetrea'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

// Exclude springboots own logging framework as we want log4j2
configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

dependencies {
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
  compile('org.springframework:spring-oxm')
  compile('org.codehaus.castor:castor-xml:1.3.3')
  compile('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1')

  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
  testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
jacoco{
  toolVersion = "0.7.9"
}
jacocoTestReport {
  group = "reporting"
  description = "generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
  additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
}

jar {
  baseName = 'securityservice'
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.cetrea.securityservice.SecurityService'
  }
}
```

Is this a gradle problem or an rpm problem?

Comment: How did you pack RPM? Try to use gradle nebula plugin

Comment: Was made with the .sh and the .spec file that ive editted in, on centOS

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid you cannot pack lib jars into uber-jar in this manner. I copy all libs into a directory and run my app with: -Djava.library.path=native and  -cp conf:your_project.jar:lib/*

Comment: Okay so how would i go about doing this? Is there an easy way to exclude all libs in gradle?

Comment: `all*.exclude group*` in my gradle file, and then copy in all the files from External libraries?

Comment: As an option. It all depends on how do you build the project. You can play with *jar* task or *dependencies { jar ... } * tasks.

Comment: I have added the gradle file to the question. Do you think you could post it as an answer? :) @AlexGera